# iPhone 4 - no provisioned iphone os is connected

Tags: iphone-4

I'm trying to install an app onto an iPhone 4 and I get:

no provisioned iphone os is connected

I am using:

- Xcode 3.2.3
- iTunes 9.2
- iPhone 4.0 with iOS 4.0 (8A293)

I have the development provisioning profile in XCode and in the phone.
The Organizer window shows the iPhone 4 with a green circle next to it.  I have the correct App ID in the bundle identifier in Info.plist.

I've tried powering on/off phone, stopping/re-starting Xcode and iTunes with no luck.
Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question: Do you have a development provisioning profile, and is it installed in Xcode and on the phone?

Comment: Yup, have the development provisioning profile in XCode and on the phone.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.  I had the build set to iPad and I was trying to download to an iPhone!  I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I had the build set to iPad and I was trying to download to an iPhone! I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If the profile is installed, you are probably trying to install the app on the device with the build configuration set to "Distribution"... you need to set it to "Debug" or "Release" in the drop-down menu in XCode on the main window.

So, build options should be "Debug" and "Device"

Comment: I've set the build options to "Debug" as well as "Release" and still get the same problem.  I always have "Device" selected.

Comment: Sounds like your provisioning file is screwed up then.  Make sure the provisioning file is still active in the Provisioning portal, follow Apple's instructions to a tee as far as installing it along with the certificate.  It's a pain, I know from experience, but once you get the hang of it it's not bad.

Comment: The provisioning profile is still active in the portal.  I install the profile by downloading it from the developer site and then copying the profile into /Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles.  Anything else I should do to install the profile?

Comment: Did you sync your device in iTunes after installing it?  I'm assuming you know this, but apple has pretty detailed instructions on their "Provisioning Portal" website.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the status of the Organizer?  From Xcode, go under Window->Organizer, and look under the DEVICES section on the left pane.  It should show the connected devices, and provide a more detailed explanation (e.g., device is not enabled for development, OS installed on phone is not supported by SDK, etc).

One possibility is that you are running 4.0.1 on your phone, but only have the 4.0 SDK installed.

Comment: Organizer shows iPhone 4 connected with green dot,
 iPhone 4 has iOS 4.0

Comment: Did you check the status of the Provisioning Profile on the phone itself?  i.e., on the iPhone, go into Settings->General->Profiles, and verify that your Provisioning profile is installed and verified.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the provisioning profile is tied to the build you are doing: Right click-> Info on the project icon in Groups & Files then Build and scroll down to Code Signing.

There seem to be a million different things that can go wrong with getting the app to the iPhone, I never get it right the first time.

I've followed this before: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/24/tutorial-list-guideline-for-building-ad-hoc-application-for-iphone/

It's for Ad Hoc but most of the steps are the same.